# How to remove auto escaping from environment variable?

Tags: python-3.3

In settings.py, I get var from environment like this:

```
ROBOTS_STR = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR')
```

My env var is set in a file and looks like:

```
DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR=User-agent: *\nDisallow: /admin\nDisallow: /api
```

The problem is that in the view, when I get settings.ROBOTS_STR, the value of the string has been auto escaped. It is: `User-agent: *\\nDisallow: /admin\\nDisallow: /api`

How can I change this behaviour? Note that I'm using Python 3.3

Answer (score 8):

Decode it with `string-escape`:

```
>>> os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR')
'User-agent: *\\nDisallow: /admin\\nDisallow: /api'
>>> os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR').decode('string-escape')
'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /admin\nDisallow: /api'
>>> print(os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR'))
User-agent: *\nDisallow: /admin\nDisallow: /api
>>> print(os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR').decode('string-escape'))
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /api
```

For Python 3, encode it first, then decode it:

```
>>> os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR').encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /admin\nDisallow: /api'
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` (Python3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try set env var with `$'xxxxxx'`:

```
$ export DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR=$'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /admin\nDisallow: /api'

>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR')
'User-agent: *\nDisallow: /admin\nDisallow: /api'
>>> print os.environ.get('DJANGO_ROBOTS_STR')
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /api
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't choose how to set the var or make an export. My env var can be declared in a file only. I tried to put $'' syntax in the file but it does not work.